# Public Cannot Access Contribution Pages

Tags: civicontribute

All of a sudden, out of blue, none of my contribution pages can be accessed by the the public. I am installed in WP and there is no "Make online contributions" permission as an option.

(From the Wiki:

Notes on Specific Permissions
Make online contributions:
If you plan to use CiviContribute and want to allow online contributions, enable this permission. Be sure to assign this permission for the "anonymous" role if you want to allow un-authenticated visitors to make contributions.)

It was all working fine and then out of the blue, it wasn't. Working with 4.7.25.

Answer (score 1):

I see the "Make Online Contributions" permission.  I found it by going to:

- Administer menu » Users and Permissions » Permissions (Access Control)
- Select "WordPress Access Control".
- Find "CiviContribute: make online contributions".  You'll probably want to check all the boxes next to it and press "Save".

See screenshots for all the steps above:
[image]

[image]

[image]